2Fauth - Docker container exited with code 1
I am trying to run a F2Auht docker container.
When I run the container based on
https://docs.2fauth.app/getting-started/installation/docker/docker-compose/
I get the following error:
2fauth  | Running version 5.0.3 commit 35f2f1d built on 2024-01-19T14:54:35Z
2fauth  | supervisord version: v0.6.8
2fauth  | PHP 8.1.22 (fpm-fcgi) (built: Aug  3 2023 23:11:21)
2fauth  | nginx version: nginx/1.22.1
2fauth  | touch: /2fauth/database.sqlite: Permission denied
2fauth exited with code 1

It seems there is an issue with the premission to write de sqlite db...
Any thoughts?

I got this when I ran the default docker-compose.yml file with sudo while following the directions.
You'll notice that the volumes section looks as follows:
    volumes:
      - ./2fauth:/2fauth

If you don't make the 2fauth directory before running docker compose, the folder gets created owned by root. If you remove and replace that directory or just change the owner to your non-root user the issue is resolved.
